# issue moving characters in a string

Tags: python

My code below:

```
randomstr = ("gdfgd asda fsdf sdf")
list = [""]
alphabet = []

for a in range(97, 123):
    alphabet.append(chr(a))

for i in range(len(randomstr)):
    list.append(randomstr[i])

    for j in range(len(alphabet)):
        if list[i] == alphabet[j]:
            list[i] = alphabet[j - 2]
    print(list[i], end='')
```

**Output:**

```
ebdeb wqbw dqbd qb
```

I'm trying to move all the characters in the list up 2 places in the alphabet(c = a, a = y).
Why does the current code print out "w" for each character "a" in randomstr?
Also how would I reverse it to move the opposite way?(y = a, a = c)

Comment: you want to reverse the alphabet in a string?

Comment: also rename your list you are using the type name as a variable name

Comment: ```"".replace("a","g")```
this replaces every occurence of a with g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your inner `for` loop you've modified `list[i]` but then the loop keeps running, resulting in it getting modified *again*.

Once you have found a match, you want to break out of the loop.

```
randomstr = ("gdfgd asda fsdf sdf")
list = [""]
alphabet = []

for a in range(97, 123):
    alphabet.append(chr(a))

for i in range(len(randomstr)):
    list.append(randomstr[i])

    for j in range(len(alphabet)):
        if list[i] == alphabet[j]:
            list[i] = alphabet[j - 2]
            break
    print(list[i], end='')
```

And of course, don't use `list` for a variable name as it is the name of a built-in type.

Another suggestion:

```
alphabet = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]
```

Can replace:

```
alphabet = []

for a in range(97, 123):
    alphabet.append(chr(a))
```